# how to use jOOQ (or something else) in such condition

Tags: java, sql, jooq

[jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) runs on generated classes (from database schema). In my apps, **there are many tables created while excuting**. Then how can I query them using jOOQ? Or can I use something else to do this?

We just use jOOQ to generate SQL, not doing any CRUD operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While being the main use case for using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), you do not have to generate any source code with jOOQ. Several users have used jOOQ the way you do, by supplying dynamic table/column names at runtime to Factory methods such as:

- [`DSL.tableByName(String...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#tableByName-java.lang.String...-)
- [`DSL.fieldByName(String...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#fieldByName-java.lang.String...-)

These methods take care of correctly escaping your schema, table, field, alias names, etc, in order to guarantee SQL syntax correctness and SQL injection protection.

Some related discussions on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jooq-user) are here:

- [Escaping SQL identifiers](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jooq-user/8_zd3b07yh4/discussion)
- [Intantiating Field and Table by name](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jooq-user/SPq6lKX-BtM/discussion)
- [Specifying the alias name for a JOIN](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jooq-user/VqSeANn7PIk/discussion)